# Joomla doesn't show the background images in embedded URL pages

Tags: joomla-2.5, css, url, bugs, images

I embedded a custom page in Joomla iframe but all the CSS declared background images are misssing. I need to configure something or put some code to show all the background images. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the CSS files defining the background images part of your Joomla site or part of the site you're embedding inside the iframe? Check your browser console to see if there are any error messages. Remember that you can't style the contents of the iframe window from your Joomla CSS files. Are you able to provide a url to your site?

Comment: The CSS is part of the site I'm embedding. My external site is shown correctly, except the background images self defined.

Answer (score 2):

go in an set the full path to the background images, this is a pain but it will fix your issue. When you include a page, sometimes the css path is not translate right,(relative url) right

eg: /images/image.jpg  <--- doesn't work
eg: http://www.somesite.com/images/image.jpg <---- will always work